# Power Pivot, Pivot Table can't expand field after Filtering

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I'm having problems with my pivot table, the data is created from Power Pivot.

I filtered my main field by a specific Name, and lose the + expand field and all of the rows not in my filter become hidden (please see example screenshot).

I tested created a regular pivot table and this error doesn't show up.

Please advise, thanks!

[image: PowerPivot Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The blue row heading indicates that the filtering is not done with the pivot table tools. If you filter the pivot table headings, you can still expand and collapse the pivot rows and the row headings stay black. If, however, you have a spreadsheet filter outside of the pivot table, that filter will turn filtered row headings blue and may hide the rows into which the pivot table expands.

[image]